# C# .net Datagrid binding from different sources

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

I have a problem using Datagrid in C# .net.

I would like to print a two dimensional array in my application and be able to add some columns.
I would like to do something like that:

```
              Student 1      Student 2
Maths    -----------  7  ----------- 5
History  -----------  6  ----------- 8
```

Then, I would like to be able to add other columns to enter the marks of other students.
My problem is that I store the mark in an object witch has a mark field and when I do not succeed to bind each column with each student's marks. Each time I try to do this, I have the same mark on each row.

I tried to do something like that:

```
BoundColumn nameColumn = new BoundColumn();
nameColumn.DataField = "Mark";
nameColumn.DataFormatString = "{0}";

this.MarksDatagrid.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
this.MarksDatagrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

this.MarksDatagrid.DataSource = listToPrint;
this.MarksDatagrid.DataBind();
```

In `listToPrint`, I have an object with a student and his mark.
Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Why don't you store students as rows and subjects as columns? This would make it easier

Comment: Actually, I would like to be able to add some students and some subjects so I don't think it would be easier (tell me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0):

you can bind datagrid like below:

```
        Maths     History
```

Student 1    50        55
Student 2    60        65

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, and sorry to answer so late. I was not here for a few days...

My problem does not concern binding actually.
My problem is to add columns.
In my application, I would like to be able to add some school subjects with an add button (it is ok for that) but I also would like to be able to add some students to give them a mark in each school subject.

As I don't know how many students there will be, I cannot add some columns in my asp file and bind them in the .cs file. 
I would like to add  some columns in dynamic way.

I don't know if I was very clear in my explanations...

Thanks for your help ;)